# Is `\quad` the same thing as a tab?

Tags: spacing, line-spacing

Consider ASCII character **9**, the tab character, sometimes written as `"\t"` in **C++**, **Java**, **Python**, etc...

In LaTeX, do you suppose that a `\quad` and a tab are the same width by default, with no customization of the settings?

Comment: surely in less time than it took to post these two questions you could have tested a file with a tab and observed it acts as a normal space.

Comment: No. Why on earth would you think that \tab and \quad would give the same space? Peter W. (GOM)

Comment: See the "Chambers Twentieth Century Dictionary (1975)", or similar, for definitions, none of which have anything to do with Muldoon's answer. The answer is related to the Latin "quod" for "four")

Comment: `\quad` is just a relative space of `1em`. It could be more or less in centimeters depending on the font. It will not change whatever the the horizontal position, and it cannot be measured in number of spaces, that for LaTeX is completely irrelevant (1  space =  2 spaces = 3 spaces +3 tabs  = the best inter-word possible space ). The most similar to tabs in plain text or some word processor is `\tab` of the package `tabto`.